# Codeigniter - Not showing any data on view

Tags: php, codeigniter

could you kind help me on this matter please. It doesn't appear on the table any data on my view which is fetch on the database. Thanks everyone for the assistance. Very much appreciated.
Here's my code:

**Controller**

```
public function index()
  {
    $this->load->helper('order_helper');
    $this->load->model('order_model');;
    $data["results"] = $this->order_model->getOrder('id', 'order_id', 'product', 'qty'); //check this parameter if it is correct

    $this->load->view('order_view', $data);
  }
```

**Model**

```
public function getOrder($id, $order_id, $product, $qty)
  {
    $rs = $this->db->get_where('order_items', array('id' => $id, 'order_id' => $order_id, 'product' => $product, 'qty' => $qty));
    return $rs->result_array();
  }
```

**View**

```
<?php foreach ($results as $result) : ?>
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $result['id']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $result['order_id']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $result['product']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $result['price']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $result['qty']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo rating($result['price'], $result['total_price']); ?></td>
        </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**Here's the output - it shouldve fetch the data on the table_name**

[image]

**It should be like this below:**

[image]

Comment: Have checked the output of `$rs->result_array()` in your model?

Comment: here  `'id', 'order_id', 'product', 'qty'` you are passing value right. once print `$data["results"] ` and check what you have got from model.

Comment: array(1) { ["results"]=> array(0) { } }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller you have this line calling the model

```
 $data["results"] = $this->order_model->getOrder('id', 'order_id', 'product', 'qty');
```

And your model is expecting a number of parameters

```
public function getOrder($id, $order_id, $product, $qty)
{
   $rs = $this->db->get_where('order_items', array('id' => $id, 'order_id' => $order_id, 'product' => $product, 'qty' => $qty));
   return $rs->result_array();
}
```

So what you are effectively doing is passing the following into the model.

```
$id = 'id', $order_id = 'order_id', $product = 'product', $qty = 'qty'
```

So you are passing in string values which I am guessing do not exist in your order_items table. (they do not)

What you need to do is to pass in actual values/strings. But looking at your code, I do not see where these values are coming from.

What you are aiming for is something like...

```
$data["results"] = $this->order_model->getOrder($id, $order_id, $product, $qty);
```

So you need to ask yourself, where are these values ( for $id, $order_id, $product and $qty) coming from?

But the actual question is Why are you doing this.

**What I suspect you are attempting to do...**

From your Code, you want to populate the View with the values from the Database. So you will need to perform a Select with NO parameters (to show this).

You could have a method called getOrders.

```
public function getOrders()
  {
    $rs = $this->db->get('order_items');
    return $rs->result_array();
  }
```

(Yes there are a few ways to write the above but keeping it kind of simple for now)

I highly recommend that you read the CodeIgniter User Guide and get more familiar with it.

I hope that helps you.

Answer (score 1):

In your model, try

```
public function getOrder($id, $order_id, $product, $qty)
{
    return $this->db->select('*')->from('order_items')->where(array('id' => $id, 'order_id' => $order_id, 'product' => $product, 'qty' => $qty))->get()->result_array();
}
```